# How to check the url in the controller slim-framework

Tags: php, url, slim, slim-3

I have problem with `slim`

I have the controllar, and 2 routs send to this controller.

1. The page html with teig.
2. The api and show that in json.

Now I need to check, if I request with this url:
`/product/{slug}`

return the twig (I do the return).

and if I request to url:`api/product/{slug}`
return me the json (i do the return).

now I don't know how to the the if request.
and how I just to know check what url request that controller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$request->getUri()->getPath()` will give you the current URL.

`$request->getAttribute('route')` will give you the current [`Route`](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/3.x/Slim/Route.php) object.